# copy to clipboard flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, clipboard

I'm trying to copy a share link to the clipboard in a flask app I have.

My html page is as follows:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(link) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)
    }
</script>

{% block content %}

    <h1 class="display-3">Sharing is caring!</h1>
    <p>Currently, the best thing to support the project is to share.</p>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="copyToClipboard('{{link}}')">Copy link</button>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

link is being sent to the page via render_template, and is generated on page load.
Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an opening `button` and a closing a `tag` and you should put your `<script>` tag inside `<head>`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="display-3">Sharing is caring!</h1>
    <p>Currently, the best thing to support the project is to share.</p>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="copyToClipboard('{{link}}')">Copy link</button>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(link) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```